# Node send a http server to child

Tags: node.js, sockets, server, parent-child, child-process

Before you even think about `cluster` is not an accepted answer for this question.

The question is quite simple, how do I send an `http.createServer()` to **multiple** children?

The problem I have is that I have a master process that is there only for monitoring and management purpose and I want my children to be able to handle either an express app and a WebSocket system.

I can't use `cluster` because it would imply too many changes in the app so what I'm looking for is an alternative.

Actual parent:

```
...
var net = require("http");
var server = net.createServer();

server.listen(C.API.LISTEN_PORT, function () {
    console.log('master is listenning');
    console.log(server);
    supervisor.on("childSpawned", function () {
        console.log('child spawned');
        supervisor.broadcast('server', {}, server); // sugar for process.send('server', server);
    });
    tracer.info(process.title + "(" + ip.address() + ")" + " says hello on port:", C.API.LISTEN_PORT);
});
```

Actual child:

```
worker.once('server', function (data) {
    data.server.on('connection', function (res) {
        console.log('got a connection on ' + process.pid);
    });
});
```

This works fine but only for 1 only child and makes connections to be handled randomly by parent and child. If I put more workers, it's a mess some are handled sometimes and that's it.

What works fine is to have the server on the parent and send the incoming socket after each connection **but** `express` and [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) do not handle to fact of being initialised by a `socket` so as I see it, the only solution is to send them a `server` in itself but how with more than 1 child (without using cluster)?

Comment: Well no choice I went with `cluster` as it seems that `child_process` has no rights to do that. I don't answer the question in case someone comes with something good one day.